# Server Rewrite rules

Tags: php, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make parameters look more attractive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796812/how-to-make-parameters-look-more-attractive)

how to print the url http://abc.xyz.com/index.php?code=pqr in the http://abc.xyz.com/pqr
using server RewriteRule ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Rewriterule ^/(.*)$ index.php?code=$1
```

Put it in the directory of your subdomain in a file name called .htaccess

Comment: but this is not working, my site is mms.xp3.biz can u please check out